# Отслеживание включенности Navigaton bar

Tags: java, android

Необходимо отслеживать наличие на экране устройства Navigation Bar. В официальной документации есть  информация об отслеживании Statusbar на экране, но нужен Navbar.То есть, если на экране есть Navbar, то его нужно перекрыть другим activity.Я пишу приложение для кастомизации Android, и скрывать Navbar не нужно, необходимо его перекрыть другим Navbar Весь гугл перегуглил, не нашел информации.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Вы хотите [скрыть Navigation Bar](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/system-ui/navigation.html) или что ?